# VBA Code is picking up a column not called out

Tags: regex, excel, vba

```
Sub UpdateDMDCLCSIM()

Dim SIM_DM_DCLC As Worksheet
Dim TextFileUpdated As Date

Set SIM_DM_DCLC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet52.Name)

TextFileUpdated = DateValue(FileDateTime("\\networkshare\dept\DCGSI\Extracts\SIM_DM_DCLC.csv"))

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Application.StatusBar = "Importing latest DM DCLC SIM Data..."


    With SIM_DM_DCLC.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;\\networkshare\dept\DCGSI\Extracts\SIM_DM_DCLC.csv" _
            , Destination:=SIM_DM_DCLC.Range("$A$1"))
            .Name = "SIM_DM_DCLC"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 936
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With


    'Change to MySQL date format.
    SIM_DM_DCLC.Range("I:K", "P:T").Replace Chr(84), " "
    SIM_DM_DCLC.Range("I:K", "P:T").Replace Chr(90), ""
    SIM_DM_DCLC.Range("I:K", "P:T").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
```

Okay so this opens a csv that is downloaded to a network share and fixes some dates.  The dates in the original file are formatted YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ and this is supposed to strip the T and Z from those dates in the appropriate columns.  The issue I am having is that for some strange reason it is processing column L in the file and I can't figure out why.

So I looked up some code for regex replace in VBA and tried to refactor the code to use the following code to try and fix the issue:

```
Sub UpdateDMDCLCSIM()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim SIM_DM_DCLC As Worksheet
    Dim TextFileUpdated As Date

    Set SIM_DM_DCLC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet52.Name)

    TextFileUpdated = DateValue(FileDateTime("\\networksharem\dept\DCGSI\Extracts\SIM_DM_DCLC.csv"))

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Application.StatusBar = "Importing latest DM DCLC SIM Data..."


        With SIM_DM_DCLC.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
                "TEXT;\\networkshare\dept\DCGSI\Extracts\SIM_DM_DCLC.csv" _
                , Destination:=SIM_DM_DCLC.Range("$A$1"))
                .Name = "SIM_DM_DCLC"
                .FieldNames = True
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                .SavePassword = False
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                .RefreshPeriod = 0
                .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
                .TextFilePlatform = 936
                .TextFileStartRow = 1
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
                .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
                .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
                .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        'Change to MySQL date format.
         Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
         regex.Pattern = "/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})Z)$/"

         For Each cell In SIM_DM_DCLC.UsedRange
              If cell.Value <> "" Then cell.Value = regex.Replace(cell.Value, "/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/")
         Next cell
```

Pretty sure that the 5017 - Application-defined or object-defined error I am getting on the regex.Replace means I have something wrong with the regex piece.  Just not sure what it is.

Comment: VBA regex declaration does not need regex delimiters, `regex.Pattern = "/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})Z)$/"` must be replaced with `regex.Pattern = "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})Z)$"`. I did not test it with your data, but at least now, it makes some sense. I also think you should provide a replacement when performing `regex.Replace`: `regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement)`

Comment: I am still getting the same error after updating the regex pattern as suggested.  I tried the replacement piece and it gave me a 450 error.

Comment: I am also open to opinions as to why the original code is performing the removal on the L column when it isn't supposed to.  Though my ideal state is to find things that look like the date time combo and fix the date time combo and set the cell format.

Comment: wow; I can't believe I didn't see this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have to check to an actual match and not just a blank; here is the updated and appropriate section of code.

```
'Change to MySQL date format.
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regex.Pattern = "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})Z)$"

For Each cell In SIM_DM_DCLC.UsedRange
    If cell.Value = regex.Pattern Then cell.Value = regex.Replace(cell.Value, "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$")
Next cell
```